# sdkaddon: How ('sdk/window/utils').openDialog can navigate to url?

Tags: firefox-addon-sdk

In sdkaddon, I have that part of code

```
win = require('sdk/window/utils').openDialog({
    features: Object.keys({
        resizable: true,
    }).join() + ',width='+w+',height='+h+',top='+pos.top+',left='+pos.left,
    name: 'mywin'
});

win.addEventListener('load', function () {
    tabs.activeTab.on('ready', function (tab) {

    });
    tabs.activeTab.url = "http://www.example.com";
});
```

which creates a new popup and goes to example.com

**How can I later change the url of  win (navigate to another url ?)**

```
win.url = "http://www.example2.com" does not work
```

Comment: what is the condition through which you'd later change the url of win?

Answer (score 0):

You are pretty close!

To open a new tab to a particular url:

```
const tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
tabs.open("http://www.example2.com");
```

That's it, there's nothing to it.